# How do I increase concentration of my 6years old daughter?

Tags: primary-schooler, attention

My daughter has a very low attention span. She is a bright child otherwise. But lack of concentration affects her studies.

Please could you recommend some activities or games that can help?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Parenting SE. I've provided a brief answer but it might not answer your question. More information would help me. Why do you think your child has a short attention span? What does she do to make you think that?

Answer (score 1):

A six year old child should be able to concentrate for about 10 to 15 minutes.  They will tend to prefer structured activities over more free-form activity. They will benefit from alternating between an activity with some moving about and activities that require sitting and thinking.

You might find that allowing your child to fidget will help - some children need to wiggle their hands around or squirm on their chair for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need make sure that your kid show avoid doing multi-tasking like. It ensure that we cannot concentrate on one single task at hand when we have a lot of tasks lying in front of kids. As most of the kids will be doing different task while studying like watching tv, or playing with things. So kids will be able to concentrate on one. Its better to avoid this kind of things.

Breaking up the study sessions he/she will not be able to concentrate for a long time in the studies. Its better to have a break while studying.

Other and important thing you need to do is you need to keep them away from sugar. You have to check the diet that he is taking for sugar content. Most of the times kids will have lot of sugar in their food they have, it results to sugar rush. It is nothing but the excessive sugar in their bloodstream that makes them hyperactive because of that he/she will not able to concentrate of one thing at a time.

Here you check out the activities http://www.kimscounselingcorner.com/2014/06/11/activities-improve-focus-attention/